# how can i re-direct a user of a particular role, if that user tries to access a page containing certain content type?

Tags: users, 7

i have set a up a role called subscriber. If a non-subscriber (authenticated or anonymous user) tries to access a page with content type of ‘video class’ i’d like to have them redirected to a page that suggestions they subscribe.  so far, the content access modules i’ve looked at don’t handle page re-directs.

is there a module that would handle that?

the Context module doesn’t seem to handle content types. I could use it to set up a block with a javascript re-direct based on user role that seems kind of flimsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) for this requirement.

You can add new rules for event such as "viewing a page" & put conditions to match user type & content type. In action you can add page redirect.